# growth predictions with GLMM using bioclimatic variables

Tags: glmm

I want to do a GLMM to predict the diameter growth of a tree species. I have data from more than 5 forest inventories in 9 different locations from 2015 to 2023. I'm not sure how to use the climate data (temperature, precipitation, wind speed) together with the age growth data for this species. Do I just need the average climate data for each year of the inventory? Or historical series of daily or monthly climate data?

I didn't try nothing yet

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example